# How to call a smart contracts method with proxy

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, etherscan

I have this smart contract: [Contract 1](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbce6a8789bb1e47fd832300a988927db32c4cc1e#code)

I need to call a method balanceOf(). But when you look inside the code or ABI, there is no method called ballanceOf().

I had the same problem with that contract [Contract 2](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd650F659aA3B0fA7ecb52F75ba4Da719c8f81B17#code)

But this contract can be called as a proxy, to access all methods.

I would like to do the same.

- How can I find out, if there is another contract (connected to Contract 1) which holds the method?
- How can I call a contract as proxy?

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Use abi of implementation contract and address of proxy contract

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).